# Pushing to windows remote fails

Tags: windows, git

I've created a repository on a windows machine at: `C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/project.git`

I've now added my remote to my local repository:
git add remote `ssh://Administrator@11.11.11.11/C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/project.git`

Now when I try to push, it gives me the following error:

```
fatal: ''/C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/project.git'' does not appear to be a git repository
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

- detect
- use

correct **technically and syntactically** ssh-URL for the repo. Current is wrong (at least in using `C:/` subpath).

I can't recall (and too lazy to STFW for you) how to write ssh-URL *automagically*, but [this topic's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348874/git-repository-url-ssh-syntax-without-absolute-path) hints and some handwork

- ssh to the server under the same user as user, which will be used to git's operations later
- find the correct (relative or absolute) path to the repo on server (`pwd`...`ls`... `cd`...)

may help